# Lambda casting rules

Tags: java, lambda, runnable

I was curious why a lambda with a return type can not be casted to a `Runnable` whereas a non void method reference can.

```
Runnable r1 = () -> 1; // not allowed
// error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
// int cannot be converted to void

Runnable r2 = ((Supplier)() -> 1)::get; // allowed
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface defines the `run` method with return type void. In a lambda expression that means that the part following the arrow `->` must be a *statement*. This is explained in [JLS §15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

The [JLS $14.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) clearly defines the syntax of a statement. As explained above it must be an "ExpressionStatement" ([§ 14.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-ExpressionStatement)). Looking there, you can find that a simple literal is not an adequate expression, but a method invocation is (even if it returns something).

Comment: Could you point where in the JLS is mentioned that, in that case, "the part following the arrow `->` must be a _statement_"? I'm looking for it.

Comment: @Tunaki Found it, it's [§15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ha perfect indeed: *If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.* And a primary expression isn't a statement expression (and isn't a block).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Wow. Thanks for finding it out. I will add this info to my answer (with your agreement).

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a “special” rule for Lambdas. It has always been acceptable to use a non-void method in a statement context (in which case, the return value is thrown away), but not so with a simple expression. For instance “String.valueOf(true);” is a valid java statement, that may occupy a line by itself, whereas “true;” is not and may not.